# ¿Por qué me devuelve como resultado NaN?

Tags: javascript

estoy realizando una calculadora de ventas use inputs para capturar los datos y JS para operarlos pero al oejectarlo en los resultados me sale NaN a que se debe que puedo cambiar
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Ds2.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: html]

Comment: Hola, si vas a incluir código porfavor asegúrate de incluirlo como texto, tiene una mejor legibilidad y facilita a otros usuarios el poder ayudarte. El código como imagen no es bien recibido. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta en cualquier momento.

Comment: Adicionalmente te invito a realizar el [tour] y ganar tu primera medalla. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

NAN significa que no s un numero
El problema es que esta ingresando como texto las variables, tienes 2 opciones... escribes

```
<input type="number" class".......>
```

o puedes en el js convertir la variable a entero con

```
parseInt(string, variable);
```

Comment: Aún declarando el input como tipo number si evalúas con typeof en JS verás que es un string

Comment: ah ok... entonces lo que debe hacer es convertirlo a entero.

Comment: Amigo gracias por tu comentario pero me sigue arrojando el mismo problema mira esta es la instrucción en JS                                            
         `<script >
 var a = parseInt(string,document.f.a.value);
 var b = parseInt(string,document.f.b.value); 
 var c = parseInt(string,document.f.c.value);
    var d = parseInt(string,document.f.d.value);
   
    function CalcularV() {
   
    d = ((a*b)/100)+(a*c)/100+a;
    document.f.d.value=d;
 }
 function calcularU(){
  
       d = a*b/100;
    document.f.d.value=d;
    }
    </script>`

Comment: El problema puede sr la carga asíncrona, intentaste poner el bloque JavaScript al final del body?

Comment: pues las variables no es que se carguen en string sino en null

Comment: logre solucionar el problema eliminando la linea d = ((a*b)/100)+(a*c)/100+a; y cambiandola por  document.f.d.value= ((a*b)/100)+(a*c)/100+a;